# Positioning an element with absolute in a media query

Tags: html, css

I am lost in what I am doing wrong with positioning the mobile menu image that I change from `display: none` to `display: inline-block` in my media query. I am trying to get the image to take on `position:absolute` and be located in the top right corner of the page with `top:30px` and `right:30px`. For some reason the image is appearing under the left image (the company logo).

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[Click here to see a jsfiddle...adjust the screen size to under 640px](https://jsfiddle.net/mqtLztuy/)

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav-inner">
        <div id="header-img">
            <a href="index"><img src="../images/psi.png"></a>
        </div><div id="nav-container">
            <a class="ssm-toggle-nav" href="#" title="Open / close"><img src="images/menu-button.png" alt="Menu" id="menu-button"></a>
            <nav id="nav-list">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Series</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Why SI</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CDCDCD;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 111;
}
#nav-inner {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#header-img {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#header-img img {
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
}
#menu-button {
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    postition: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-container {
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#nav-list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.nav-link a {
    color: #009ED2;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-link-active a {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav-link-active a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 80%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #0f5233;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
}

/*----------------------------------------------MEDIA QUERY 640--------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #FFF;
    border-left: 2px solid #CDCDCD;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 111;
}
#nav-inner {
    width: 90%;
}
#header-img {
    width: 40%;
}
#header-img img {
    height: 100px;
}
#menu-button {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav-container {
    width: 59%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    background: #009ED2;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: visible;
    transform: translate(100%,0);
}
.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-link a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, can you give us a better demo? We need a [mcve] of the current problem. All I see now are a couple of broken images and the only thing I see that is absolutely positioned is `.nav-link-active a:after`

Comment: It is in the main part of the css. For `#menu-button`

Comment: Even with the broken images, it still works. you can see the menu-button image is right after the left image. I am wanting it to be in the top right corner.

Comment: @Armin Wow.. stupid typos. Even after that is fixed, the image is going far down rather than being 30px from the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `position` as `postition`. `#nav-container` needs `vertical-align: top` to align at the top of the container, and changed the `top` and `right`values for `#menu-button` to `0` so it will be in the top/right.

https://jsfiddle.net/mqtLztuy/1/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Inside `#menu-button` you have `postition: absolute;` instead of `position:absolute`. Remove `position: relative` from `#nav-container`

Comment: Even after that is fixed, the image is going far down rather than being 30px from the top

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell with some of the broken structure and missing images, but...I'm not seeing it shift under the logo. It's sticking to the right (albeit too far from the right).

One thing I can tell you: you've spelled **"position"** wrong for **#menu-button**. You wrote "postition". Though, you probably shouldn't apply it so far down the totem pole (to the image itself). Try this:

1.
Changing:

```
#nav-menu {
 width: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 right: 30px;
 top:30px;
}
```

2. Removing **position:absolute;" from your #menu-button